# Rendering a textured quad in LWJGL is rendering White?

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl

I am trying to render a textured quad onto the screen as a start menu button for my new game. But when rendering it just renders as a white quad, i have searched for days over the internet and i havent found a single answer that has fixed the problem.

My texture is wood.png and it is in a "res" folder inside a resources source folder in the project. it is a 128 * 128 pixel image.

The code for rendering textures is as follows:

```
public static void renderTexture(Texture texture, float width, float height, float x, float y) {

    texture.bind();

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    texture.bind();
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(width, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(width, height);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, height);
        glLoadIdentity();
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

The code that i use to load the textures is:

```
    public static Texture loadTexture(String fileName){
    try {
        Texture texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/"+fileName+".png"));
        return texture;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have a static Texture storing `private static Texture startTex = Loader.loadTexture("wood");` and i render it every frame by doing:

```
RenderSystem.renderTexture(startTex, 200, 200, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is that i did `glBegin(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` instead of `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`
Sorry the code for that part wasnt shown.